# Cassandra unlimited row response

Tags: python, database, cassandra

I'm using the Cassandra python driver working containing a table with 38500000 rows. I'm benchmarking various databases with a product I'm we're developing. To benchmark selection I use a filter that should return around half the rows with 3 selection columns (then I vary the selection columns to see which perform best). However when working with Cassandra I only get 57016 results each time per query (which must be some cap). I've tried using SimpleStatement and setting `fetch_size = 38500000` but this didn't work. I was wondering if there's some parameter I should be changing as I can't find anything in the documentation apart from how Cassandra breaks down pages that go beyond the `fetch_size`.

[EDIT]

To add some more information the query returns:

`cassandra.ReadFailure: Error from server: code=1300 [Replica(s) failed to execute read] message="Operation failed - received 0 responses and 1 failures" info={'consistency': 'LOCAL_ONE', 'required_responses': 1, 'received_responses': 0, 'failures': 1}`
after I used `session.default_fetch_size = None`. Then after increasing tombstones to `tombstone_failure_threshold: 10000000` and letting `gc_grace_seconds = 0` I still get the same error. I've also gone into Cluster.py and set the `_default_timeout = 1000` but that didn't lead to anything.

[EDIT 2]
Going through the debug console the error is:
`<SELECT * FROM mydb.facttable WHERE int64 > 0 LIMIT 38500000>, total time 5007 msec, timeout 5000 msec`, so again where can I modify the timeout 5000msec parameter?

Answer (score 5):

Hy there.

Good news is I think I can explain your situation and problems but the bad news is I don't think there is an easy fix.

To give you the short answer and solution:
The read fails because Cassandra has safeguards in place to prevent "malfunctioning" or "rogue" queries from compromising the performance of the whole cluster. For this reason there is a read timeout (as you discovered yourself in EDIT2) that defaults to *5000ms*.
**If you need to increase that value, you need to modify `read_request_timeout_in_ms` in *cassandra.yaml***.

This however is not a real solution.

Now, for the long answer:
From what I understand you are targeting with your query 38M rows that you want Cassandra to filter and then return approximately 19M rows. I could see this value achieved on production hardware with well designed tables and a lot of fine-tuning.
Given the info in EDIT1, it looks like you are using a one node cluster so I imagine this is a small development node maybe even hosted on your laptop/pc. While sharing the table schema and query could have provided more info and lead to more advice, overall the problem remains that you are trying to run a task on a clearly under-powered cluster(node actually).
From you data, the node was able to process just over 20k rows per second(and return 10k) before timing out. From my experience this seems consistent with a low resource devel node. Extrapolating from this, it would take your node around **half an hour to go trough 38M records** assuming it will have the memory to do so and no other configuration will pose problems (if I didn't messe up the calculations). That is a very long time for a query, even for an administrative one.
When trying to work with so many rows you should not only try to have proportional HW to run the queries against but also:

1. Avoid full scans (you should always try and hit a single partition, if that is not the case you should probably rethink the DB model);
2. Most partitions **should** be under 10MB and all **should** be under 100MB;
3. Partitions while hard-capped at 2 billion cells((no. of rows) * (avg. no. of cells per row)) should usually remain under 100k cells.

Given the 3 "best practices" generally accepted as such, and the data you provided, I am inclined to believe that you are not implementing at least 2 of the 3. That and combined with under-powered HW leads to a lack of a simple solution (like just increasing the timeout value).
My suggestion to really resolve the problem is:

- If you are only doing this to test your code or different approaches, then use a proportional amount of data with the power of the devel "server" compared to your production one. You should still make sure the model you are using cold be effectively run in production given that the large amount of required rows make me think there might be a problem with the DB model.
- Open another question with information about your situation, current schema and desired outcome and you could receive help on modeling your use-case. While Cassandra can be very powerful when used right, it can be extremely inefficient when badly used.

Hope this helped,
Cheers.

Comment: Thanks this clears a few things up. I edited all the cassandra.yaml parameters but this lead to nothing (which is why I went edited the python package). The table is on a single node, a GP-BM1-S terraform sever (https://www.scaleway.com/en/pricing/). The issue is when I use Clickhouse or LocustDB I get response times of 4-7s, and on MariaDB around 40s. So why does Cassandra take so much longer? Also when setting up the table I have 16 rows of which a composite key, with the partition key being 100000 rows long and the composite key iterating this 385 times which works fine on all other setups.

Comment: @JohnMiller  Well, first of, did you edit read_request_timeout_in_ms and if yes did it produce any changes? It should have. Looking at the specs it really is strager that you got such bad results. On specs like that you should have been able to process way more even if you were doing it inefficiently. Well if the partition has 100k rows it means that you are doing a full table scan. Can you pelase explain what you mean by "composite key iterating this 385"? Could you also make a quick calculation of the size of a partition?( sum of the avg. size of the 16 columns *100k)

Comment: @JohnMiller Could you also provide some info about your setup? How is cassandra installed on the instance and most important did you monitor the resource usage during the query? (i recommend dstat with the memory option (-am) over using top). As another idea, please run the query with trace on and try and provide at least part of the return values. Tkx.

Comment: Sorry but I'm closing the question, I have strict deadlines for my internship and Cassandra doesn't look like a good DBMS to compete with LocustDB, Clickhouse etc.